# Adjusting Apache Solr bias based on content length?

Tags: 7, search

I have a site using the [Apache Solr Search Integration module](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) with a short-form content type that is getting weighted too highly in the Solr index. I've tried adding "Bias" to the other content types and leaving the short-form content type set to *Ignore*, but even with other bias settings maximized the short pieces still rise to the top. Looking at the particular items that appear at the top, it seems to be that multiple instances of the search terms in a short piece cause it to rank higher.

According to the help on the bias settings page, "Any value except *Ignore* will increase the score of the given type in search results." Is that a limitation of the Solr module or of Solr itself? Ideally, I'd like to **decrease** the relevance of the short type. What are my options for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Under bias setting you should be able to reduce the priority of the fields. So reduce the priority of the fields that is not much important, and increase the priority of the fields that you would prefer for solar to prioritize.

The settings can be found on: `admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings/solr/bias`

0.1 is the lowest and 21.0 is the highest rating.

Comment: In this case, the field in question is the body. I need the body field to be weighted differently, depending on the content type. Plus, as I mentioned in the question, the help text specifically says "**Any value** except Ignore will **increase** the score of the given type in search results."

Comment: yes, as the help text says if you select the ignore the field will not be considered for searching

Comment: once after making the changes, you need to index the search environment and run cron once, so that your new settings will sync-up with acquia search.

Usually it take some time to get updated